# Is it a bad practice to consider an interfaced parameter as a concrete one?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have the following classes :

```
<?php

class SaveEvent implements EventInterface
{
    private $_path;

    public function __construct($path) { $this->_path = $path; }
    public function getName() { return 'save'; }
    public function getPath() { return $this->_path; }
}

class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function update(EventInterface $event)
    {
        switch ($event->getName()) {
            case 'save':
                $path = $event->getPath();
                file_put_contents($path, 'File saved');
                break;
            case 'quit':
                // Other event
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my "update" method takes in parameter an EventInterface and according to the kind of event will trigger a specific process. It's about the same implementation than SplSubject / SplObserver but instead of passing my subject to my observers I will pass an event (that eventually can contain data).

My observer will listen for a "save" event, event linked to a file path, and will stored the string "File saved" on this path.

Is it a bad practice to accept an "interfaced" parameter, check its concrete type and to consider it like its concrete type after?

If yes which solution do you propose to solve this problem?

PS: I'm not satisfied on title and tags I set for this topic, if you have better please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I see here is that you are expecting one of several specific implementations of the interface.  Sometimes that is OK, if you are optimizing, but I'd normally expect to see that with declared class names, such as:

```
if ($event instanceof MyConcreteEvent) {
    // ...
}
```

If you are implementing an event dispatcher, then you would subscribe classes to the `Observer` which listen for a specific `$event->getName()`.

The observer would then iterate over the subscribers, calling each one.  If there are no subscribers listening for the event, then nothing should happen.

Checkout http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/index.html for information on events.

I know the Observer and Event Dispatcher are separate patterns, but at their hearts they are the same thing.

Comment: ok so you're not surprised by the use of a SaveEvent specific method whereas the method accept an interfaced generic object ?

Comment: @benjamin.cohen-solal If you were using a statically typed language then your code wouldn't work, because `getPath` is not a method of `EventInterface`, the compiler would complain.  However, PHP is dynamic, so your code will work, just so long as no "other" events with the name "save" are used that don't also implement `getPath`.  You don't need to worry about this too much, but using subscribers will help you mitigate any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice because you might have another class (implementing the same interface) that has a similar/exact behavior but with different algorithm and it can be easily decoupled.

This is a strategy desing pattern (see more patterns here: http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#strategy )

### Example

```
    class YYYScraper implements LinkScraper
    {
        public function getLinks() {
        //gets links from the site www.yyy.com specific for this because the site has a different structure from the class below
        } 
    }
    class XXXScraper implements LinkScraper
    {
        public function getLinks() {
        //gets links from the site www.xxx.com
        } 
    }

class ProcessService
{
    public function gatherLinks(LinkScraper $linkScraper)
    {
        $linkScraper->getLinks();
        //save them or smth
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't understand how to apply strategy design pattern to my problem

Answer (score 0):

In your example update method tends to become bigger and bigger, and do too much. It becomes difficult to read.

The best choice would be to implement each event type as a method in the observer class like:

```
class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function save(SaveEvent $event)
    {
        $path = $event->getPath();
        file_put_contents($path, 'File saved');
    }

    public function quit(QuitEvent $event)
    {
        // Other event
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.